# How to connect to localhost web server from Android Emulator?

Tags: android, localhost

I want to check the connection status of my localhost web server from my Android code. But i am getting same result "**Not Connected**" in both Online / Offline cases.

I don't understant how can i do it. I also gave the permission to Internet in Manifest file

**Java Code**

```
     try
     {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/ABC");

            httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            tt.setText(" Connected to Localhost ");

    }       
    catch(Exception e)
    {

            tt.setText(" Not Connected ");

    }
```

**Manifest File :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is my above code and please let me know , what could be the solution.

Comment: Log the exception stacktrace to see your problem, e.g. add `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch block.

Comment: i am getting NetworkOnMainThreadException , please suggest me what kind of exception this is ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX; StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp); thank man , this code works ....